Closed form for a linear recurrence relation of varying order
In my research I have come across a recurrence relation that is of varying order. The relation is as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
f_0=f_1=0,\\ 
f_2=1,\\ 
\bigg(f_{2\rho}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\rho}f_i\bigg)\wedge \big(f_{2\rho-1}=f_{2\rho}\big),\quad\forall\rho\geq2.
\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Note that the order is varying, that is, it is not of the form of Fibonacci numbers of order $2$
$$
\begin{cases}
f_0=0,\\
f_1=1 \\
f_n = f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}
\end{cases},
$$
or more generally of order $m$ (independent of $n$)
$$
f_n = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{i}f_{n-i},
$$
with values of $f_{j}$ where $0\leq j\leq m-1$ are given along with the integers $\alpha_i$.
I am aware of methods of getting a closed form for linear recurrence relations of order $2$ and $3$ and hopefully there exists similar methods for any fixed order $m$. However, I am not sure how to solve the case where $m$ depends on $n$ as with equation \eqref{1}. Any references and/or comments are highly appreciated.

I wouldn't expect a closed form, but there might be a nice expression using the binary expansion of $n+1$

I am not sure how $n+1$ relates to the variables in equation (1). Would you please elaborate?

Have you tried computing the first 100 values and searching OEIS? Since odd and even entries are pairwise equal beginning from $f_3=f_4$, it would seem useful to search for just the even values $f_4,f_6,f_8,f_{10},\ldots$

How is $f_3$ computed? I do not understand your notation, really.
If I just code it as it says, the even-indexed numbers, starting from 2, are
{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 18, 23, 30, 37, 47, 57, 70, 83, 101, 119,
142, 165, 195, 225, 262, 299, 346, 393} which does not seem to give a hit in the OEIS. Differences of these give back the original (full sequence) more or less.

@Per: With $\rho=2$ the recurrence says $f_3=f_4$.

@JukkaKohonen: Thanks for letting me know about the online resource. This looks very useful!

Since we have an explicit recurrence that is easy to compute, it makes sense to do an OEIS lookup.
If I understood and coded the recurrence correctly, the sequence starts:
$$
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 10, 10, 13, 13, 18, 18, 23, 23, 30, 30, 37, 37, 47, 47, 57, 57, 70, 70, 83, 83, 101, 101, 119, 119, 142, 142, 165, 165, 195, 195, 225, 225
$$
Leaving out a few initial terms (usually good for searches, because different versions might start from different positions), and entering only even-numbered terms we find A033485, with title "a(n) = a(n-1) + a(floor(n/2)), a(1) = 1." and this comment:

Partial sums of the sequence a(1)=1, a(1), a(1), a(2), a(2), a(3),
a(3), a(4), a(4), a(5), a(5), a(6), ...; example: a(1) = 1, a(2) = 1+1
= 2, a(3) = 1+1+1 = 3, a(4) = 1+1+1+2 = 5, a(5) = 1+1+1+2+2 = 7, ... - Philippe Deléham, Jan 02 2004

It seems to be exactly the sequence being sought. No closed form seems to be given, but links and other information are found.
